# Can't add circular mask in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mask

I am creating a `UITableViewCell` object and returning it inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function in `tableView`. I have a `UIView` in the cell which I want to make circular. Using the code from [this link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-circular-image-calayer/), I had written following code:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = UITableViewCell()

     let containerDP = UIView()
    containerDP.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    // some code 

   let firstLetter = UILabel()
        firstLetter.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
                    firstLetter.text = (data[indexPath.row].UserObject.FirstName! as String).uppercaseString[0]

        firstLetter.font = UIFont(name: firstLetter.font.fontName, size: 50)
        firstLetter.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        firstLetter.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        firstLetter.layer.cornerRadius = firstLetter.frame.size.width / 2;
        firstLetter.clipsToBounds = true

        containerDP.addSubview(firstLetter)
        firstLetter.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.center.equalTo(containerDP)
            make.edges.equalTo(containerDP).inset(UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10))

        }

      // some code 


    return cell

    }
```

But there is still no circular mask:

[image]

Comment: did you try masktoBounds = true

Comment: are you imported the quartzcore framework

Comment: @MohamadFarhand: yes, still not working

Comment: @Vishal plz add quartzcore framework , also subclass your UILabel and do it in drawinrect()

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = UITableViewCell()

     let containerDP = UIView()
    containerDP.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    // some code 

   let firstLetter = UILabel()
        firstLetter.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
                    firstLetter.text = (data[indexPath.row].UserObject.FirstName! as String).uppercaseString[0]

        firstLetter.font = UIFont(name: firstLetter.font.fontName, size: 50)
        firstLetter.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        firstLetter.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

        firstLetter.layer.cornerRadius = firstLetter.frame.size.width / 2;
        firstLetter.layer.masksToBounds = true 
        firstLetter.clipsToBounds = true

        containerDP.addSubview(firstLetter)
        firstLetter.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.center.equalTo(containerDP)
            make.edges.equalTo(containerDP).inset(UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10))

        }

      // some code 


    return cell

    }
```

Comment: Using firstLetter.layer.masksToBounds = true and    firstLetter.clipsToBounds = true also doesnt work

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` for tablewView cell creating and caching
2. Make subview setups for tableViewCell in `awakeFromNib` method
3. With `clipsToBounds = true` it should work

Comment: I need to create it dynamically

Comment: Create this label by default in cell and hide it, or create new type of cell. But creating tableViewCell every time in cellForRowAtIndexPath is wrong way

Answer (score 0):

- first you should create a `customtableviewCell` class for your tableview.
- then make `IBOutlet` connection to your cutomtablviewCell
- then `#import` your `customtablviewCell` to your `tableviewController`
- then inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method(I'm well in objectiveC, not in swift) call to your `cutomTableviewcell` like below

  customTableviewCell *cell = [your code here];
- after that do your styles like

  cell.fisrtLetter.layer.cornerRadius = cell.firstletter.frame.size.width/2;
      cell.firstLetter.layer.masksToBounds = true;
- please get the idea.